# (nodejs gmail-api) Store messages in array?

Tags: node.js, arrays, gmail-api

I have a function that prints in the console all the unread messages. I'd like to store these messages in an array that I could use again later in the code. Is that possible ?

````js
 async function listMessages(auth, query) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});
    gmail.users.messages.list(
      {
        userId: 'me',
        q: query,
      }, (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
          return;
        }
        if (!res.data.messages) {
          resolve([]);
          return;
        }
        console.log(res.data.messages);
        resolve(res.data.messages);
      }    
    );  
  })
;}```
````

Comment: Can you provide the context in which `listMessages` is getting called, and where do you want to use that data?

Answer (score 0):

myNewMessage as your message:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push(myNewMessage)
```